# How to divide an array by an other array element wise in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, division

I have two arrays, and I want all the elements of one to be divided by the second. For example,

```
In [24]: a = np.array([1,2,3])                                                      

In [25]: b = np.array([1,2,3])                                                      

In [26]: a/b                                                                        
Out[26]: array([1., 1., 1.])

In [27]: 1/b                                                                        
Out[27]: array([1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333])
```

[image]

This is not the answer I want, the output I want is like (we can see all of the elements of a are divided by b)

```
In [28]: c = []                                                                     

In [29]: for i in a: 
    ...:     c.append(i/b) 
    ...:                                                                            

In [30]: c                                                                          
Out[30]: 
[array([1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333]),
 array([2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667]),
In [34]: np.array(c)                                                                
Out[34]: 
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
       [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
       [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]])
```

[image]

But I don't like for loop, it's too slow for big data, so is there a function that included in numpy package or any good (faster) way to solve this problem?

Comment: As the output, do you want a single array that contains the result of each element of `a` divided by the corresponding element of `b`?

Comment: Please provide the code as actual code/text instead of images. This is for three reasons, the place where the images are hosted might remove them, text is searchable my search-engines, its easier for others to copy the code when they try to help you.

Comment: Please add actual code instead of images.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your patience in answering my questions. I have added the actual code in the text.

Answer (score 6):

It is simple to do in pure numpy, you can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to calculate the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) (or any other outer operation) of two vectors:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 4)
b = np.arange(1, 4)

c = a[:,np.newaxis] / b

# array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
#        [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
#        [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]])
```

This works, since `a[:,np.newaxis]` increases the dimension of the `(3,)` shaped array `a` into a `(3, 1)` shaped array, which can be used for the desired broadcasting operation.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to cast `a` into a 2D array (same shape as the output), then repeat for the dimension you want to loop over. Then vectorized division will work.

```
>>> a.reshape(-1,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> a.reshape(-1,1).repeat(b.shape[0], axis=1) 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])


>>> a.reshape(-1,1).repeat(b.shape[0], axis=1) / b
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
       [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
       [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]])


# Transpose will let you do it the other way around, but then you just get 1 for everything
>>> a.reshape(-1,1).repeat(b.shape[0], axis=1).T
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

>>> a.reshape(-1,1).repeat(b.shape[0], axis=1).T / b
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

print(a.reshape(-1, 1) / b)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [[ 1.          0.5         0.33333333]
>  [ 2.          1.          0.66666667]
>  [ 3.          1.5         1.        ]]
> ```